# Exception when running the application program

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I just did my code for the assignment. But when I tried to run the code, I had issues trying to run the JavaFX GUI here.
My code is this as a reference :

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    
    Stage stage;
    Scene scene;
    Scene RegisterScene;
    BorderPane RegisterBP;
    GridPane RegisterGP;
    Label RegistLbl;
    Label NameLabel, AgeLabel, ClassLabel, SchoolLabel;
    TextField NameField;
    TextArea AddressTA;
    Spinner<Integer> AgeSpinner;
    SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> AgeFactory;
    Spinner<Double> ClassSpinner;
    SpinnerValueFactory<Double> ClassFactory;
    ComboBox<String> SchoolBox;
    Button SubmitButton, DeleteButton, OpenFileButton;
    FileChooser FileChooser;
    
    TableView<Student> table;
    TableColumn<Student, String> NameColumn, SchoolColumn;
    TableColumn<Student, Integer> AgeColumn;
    TableColumn<Student, Double> ClassColumn;
    
    Alert NameAlert;
    
    ScrollPane sp;

    public void initialize() {
        RegisterBP = new BorderPane();
        RegisterScene = new Scene(RegisterBP, 1366, 768);
        RegisterGP = new GridPane();
        
        sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(RegisterBP);
        sp.setFitToWidth(true);
        
        RegistLbl = new Label("Registration");
        NameLabel = new Label("Name");
        AgeLabel = new Label("Age");
        ClassLabel = new Label("Class");
        SchoolLabel = new Label("School origin");
        
        NameField = new TextField();
        AgeSpinner = new Spinner<>();
        AgeSpinner = setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 100, 1));
        ClassSpinner = setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(1, 100, 1));
        AddressTA = new TextArea();
        SchoolBox = new ComboBox<>();
        SchoolBox.getItems().addAll("Otonokizaka High School", "Uranohoshi Girls High School", "Nijigasaki High School");
        SchoolBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        SubmitButton = new Button("Register");
        DeleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        
        OpenFileButton = new Button("Open File");
        FileChooser = new FileChooser();
        
        
    }
    
    private Spinner<Double> setValueFactory(DoubleSpinnerValueFactory doubleSpinnerValueFactory) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private Spinner<Integer> setValueFactory(IntegerSpinnerValueFactory integerSpinnerValueFactory) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void TableInitialization() {
        table = new TableView<>();
        
        NameColumn = new TableColumn<Student, String>("Name");
        NameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("name"));
        NameColumn.setMinWidth(RegisterBP.getWidth() / 4);
        
        AgeColumn = new TableColumn<Student, Integer>("Age");
        AgeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Integer>("age"));
        AgeColumn.setMinWidth(RegisterBP.getWidth() / 4);
        
        ClassColumn = new TableColumn<Student, Double>("Class");
        ClassColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Double>("class"));
        ClassColumn.setMinWidth(RegisterBP.getWidth() / 4);
        
        SchoolColumn = new TableColumn<Student, String>("School origin");
        SchoolColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("school"));
        SchoolColumn.setMinWidth(RegisterBP.getWidth() / 4);
            
        table.getColumns().addAll(NameColumn, AgeColumn, ClassColumn, SchoolColumn);
        }
    
    public void initAlert() {
        NameAlert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        NameAlert.setHeaderText("Invalid name!");
        NameAlert.setContentText("You must insert at least 3 characters");
    }
    
    public void PositionSetting() {
        RegisterGP.add(NameLabel, 0, 0);
        RegisterGP.add(AgeLabel, 0, 1);
        RegisterGP.add(ClassLabel, 0, 2);
        RegisterGP.add(SchoolLabel, 0, 3);
        RegisterGP.add(SubmitButton, 0, 4);
        
        RegisterGP.add(NameField, 1, 0);
        RegisterGP.add(AgeSpinner, 1, 1);
        RegisterGP.add(ClassSpinner, 1, 2);
        RegisterGP.add(SchoolBox, 1, 3);
        RegisterGP.add(DeleteButton, 1, 4);

        RegisterGP.setHgap(15);
        RegisterGP.setVgap(10);
        RegisterGP.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        
        RegisterBP.setTop(RegistLbl);
        RegisterBP.setCenter(table);
        
    }
    
    public void SetEventHandler() {
        SubmitButton.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) this);
        DeleteButton.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) this);
        OpenFileButton.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) this);


    }
    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setScene(RegisterScene);
        stage.setTitle("Student List");
        stage.show();
        initialize();
        TableInitialization();
        PositionSetting();
        
    }
}
`
```

The moment I tried to run the app however, I can't run it because it would always ended up with me getting caught by this :

```
`Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getProperties()" because "<parameter1>" is null
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Pane.setConstraint(Pane.java:111)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.setRowIndex(GridPane.java:299)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.setConstraints(GridPane.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.add(GridPane.java:973)
    at gslcpertemuanke9/application.Main.PositionSetting(Main.java:135)
    at gslcpertemuanke9/application.Main.start(Main.java:167)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
`
```

Any solutions to this, kindly please?

Comment: This may sound trivial, but it is not.  Please follow *all* [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for *all* code posted publicly.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a variable to a value, then setting it again to null and trying to use the null value in an API that does not accept null values.

You write this:

```
AgeSpinner = new Spinner<>();
AgeSpinner = setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 100, 1));
```

And:

```
private Spinner<Double> setValueFactory(DoubleSpinnerValueFactory doubleSpinnerValueFactory) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

So you are setting the AgeSpinner to a value, then you are immediately setting it to null.

You then attempt to add the spinner to a GridPane:

```
RegisterGP.add(AgeSpinner, 1, 1);
```

But the AgeSpinner is null and the GridPane throws an exception because it doesn't make sense to put a null value in a GridPane.

**Study Recommendations**

- [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)
- Microsoft's tutorial on [how to debug code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp),

  - The Microsoft tutorial uses Visual Studio Code and C# or Visual Basic, so I don't advise following it directly (as it is not Java), but the article contains good info on how to debug.
- Intellij info on [debugging Java](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html#stopping-debugger).
- Also, simple `System.out.println()` statements can help you understand what is going on in the code.

Why? Because the error I provided info on isn't the only null value in the code, you will need to find the others and fix them.

Comment: I'll try to use the methods you mentioned here. Thanks for the information regarding the problem there.

Comment: It appears I shouldn't use the "=" for the AgeSpinner ones which is why I got caught there. I also forgot to add the ClassSpinner variable which explains as well.